# Powershell invoke script in new process and within the same runspace

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, process, runspace

I got within my application (process) an already configured c# [Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) v3.
I want to execute my PowerShell script in a new process, but within the same Runspace.
How could I accomplish this?
I thought, when I start a PowerShell within an existing runspace, then that Runspace will be inherited to the new PowerShell: Unfortunately, this was not the case...

I have seen following interesting methods, but got no solution how these could help:
[RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacefactory.createoutofprocessrunspace?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)
[Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1)

PS: I can not change within my app the access from Runspace to a [PowerShellProcessInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.powershellprocessinstance?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)  and also I can not use [PSRemoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Please justify the -1

Comment: I didn't vote on your question yet, but a runspace can't span multiple processes, so your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: Thanks for your message, so if Runspaces are not "shareable" within different processes this should be the answer to my question. It would be nice if you could write it as an answer with more information, like for instance the some Microsoft sources, where this is explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is impossible - a single runspace cannot span multiple processes.

Allow me to demonstrate the relevant hierarchical relationships with this state of the art graphic I whipped up in `mspaint`:

[image]

A runspace is bound to a single .NET AppDomain, and an AppDomain cannot span multiple processes.